# Integration test flutter packages incompatible with a lot of other packages

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration

When trying to implement flutter integration test in dev_dependencies, while running pub get, the output is that integration test flutter dependencies versions are incompatible with other plug-ins. I get the next error:

```
[-] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in --...                       
Because no versions of test_coverage_badge match >0.2.0 <0.3.0 and test_coverage_badge 0.2.0 depends on args ^2.0.0, test_coverage_badge ^0.2.0 requires args ^2.0.0.

And because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on args 1.6.0, test_coverage_badge ^0.2.0 is incompatible with integration_test from sdk.

So, because -- depends on both integration_test any from sdk and test_coverage_badge ^0.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because -- depends on both integration_test any from sdk and test_coverage_badge ^0.2.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

When I solve this one, there are a lot of others.
Is flutter integration outdated? Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

flutter doctor -v output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.4 at C:\Users\davor\flutter
    • Framework revision b1395592de (2 weeks ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 2dce47073a
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\davor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\davor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\davor\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dart.dev/null-safety#known-issues still testing related packages are not migrate to null safety, it will expected mid of 2021